# Huawei File Safe Stuck/not working

Tags: encryption, restore, huawei, files

I have created a safe on the SD using the files app on my Huawei P20 Lite.
It worked fine, until I decided to create a second one. Now, it no longer asks for my fingerprint, but for my password. After entering it, it brings me to a safe selection screen.
[image: the screen]
Selecting the one that is in use does nothing. Selecting the other one brings me back to the password entry screen  after which the process repeats.
I have tried deleting all but one safe from the SD card, and resetting the password. Both methods do nothing. Creating a new safe lets me add files to it until I exit  at which point the process repeats.

Q: *How do I enter a safe or reset it entirely so I can create a new one?*

Answer (score 1):

Unless someone figures something else, here are my findings:

- Huawei will let you create multiple safes. However, doing so will cause you to enter an infinite loop of login screens that you cannot "exit" to enter either safe.
- The only way to fix this is to delete the `.File_SafeBox` folder from the root of your SD card.
- All files will be destroyed.